# Replacing image in sprite - cocos2d game development of iPhone

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I want to change the sprite image.

Say for example:

```
mainSprite=[Sprite spriteWithFile:@"redFile.png"];
[self addChild:mainSprite];
```

Here, Sprite is already added to a layer. I have mainSprite (pointer) which can access it.

If I change

```
[mainSprite setOpacity:150];
```

it works perfectly. But here I want to change the sprite image instead of opacity.

But I don't know how.

Comment: i think this link will help
[change ccsprite image in cocos2d](http://www.ccsprite.com/cocos2d/change-sprite-image-after-created.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@sagar:
In cocos2d 0.99.x I use

```
[sprite setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"sprite.png"]];
```

It works. The next question is, how can I get back to my previous sprite? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Ok. Damn Simple.

I find it by R & D.

```
Texture2D *x=[[Texture2D alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"box-purple-dark.png"]];
[mainSprite setTexture:x];
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace image in sprite :

```
CCTexture2D *tex1 = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"new-image.png"];
[mainSprite setTexture:tex1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace image in sprite :

```
[sprite setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"image.png"]];
```